# ConstraintLayout: Unable to Wrap_Content and Stack RecyclerView Items

Tags: java, android, xml, android-recyclerview, android-constraintlayout

I have a RecyclerView I am trying to populate with a CardView objects. The root view for each is ConstraintLayout.

I want the cards in my Recyclerview to each occupy 25% of the vertical screen space and be stacked. I have used various guidelines to set these constraints.

I am noticing that while I can view the CardView, there is plenty of space in betweeen cards. It appears the RecyclerView is populating views that are the height of match_parent, when I want the CardView Stacked on each other:

RecyclerView:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recycler_view_ingredients"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >

</android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
```

Individual CardView:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.constraint.Guideline
    android:id="@+id/guideline_zero"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_constraintGuide_percent=".025" />

<android.support.constraint.Guideline

    android:id="@+id/guideline_one"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.975" />

<android.support.constraint.Guideline
    android:id="@+id/guideline_two"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.025" />

<android.support.constraint.Guideline
    android:id="@+id/guideline_four"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.25" />

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/recipe_cardview"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guideline_one"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline_zero"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guideline_two"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guideline_four">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/id_of_recipe_item"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center" />

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2):

It is the `ConstraintLayout` that determines the height of each `RecyclerView` item. Since the height of the `ConstraintLayout` is `match_parent` each item will take up the entire screen. Within the `ConstraintLayout`, the `CardView` will take 25%. The remaining 75% will be blank. This is why you are seeing what your report.

So, you need a way to make the `ConstraintLayout` be 25% of the screen's height. Unfortunately, there is no way to specify a 25% height for children of a `RecyclerView` directly except through code. *(This is not exactly true: If you have the `RecyclerVIew` defined at `100dp`, for example, you can define the `ConstraintLayout` as `25dp` and be done with it. I assume that you do not want to specify exact heights in your code.)*

To get to a 25% height, you will need to determine the height of the `RecyclerView` *after layout* and set the height of the `ConstraintLayout` in `onCreateViewHolder()` of the adapter for the `RecyclerView`.

Comment: I would think there is an attribute of the ConstraintLayout, but it appears to be a limitation. I cannot use my Guidelines for the root ConstraintLayout?

Comment: @tccpg288 A guidelines can only be referenced by siblings of the guideline. A guideline cannot reach outside its `ConstraintLayout` to change the size of the layout.

Comment: Got it, I see this as somewhat of a limitation of the ConstraintLayout, would you agree? It essentially does not have a wrap_content feature, and when I apply wrap_content to the Constraint_Layout for the RecyclerView items it minimizes all my views.